# jQuery parent-child check-boxes not hide properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created nested parent-child check-boxes. when you checked on parent checkbox then child showing properly, but when you un-checked any parent checkbox it hide all check-boxes.

Here is jQuery code in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6296B/

To track issue please follow steps:

1. checked on 100
2. then checked on 120
3. then checked on 123
4. then un-check 123

You will got the issue automatically.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
          {
              $(".checkbox-container input[type='checkbox']").change(function()
              {
                  if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                  { 
                       $(this).parents("li").children("ul").show(600);
                  }
                  else {  $(this).parents("li").children("ul").hide(600); }
              });
          });
    </script>
<style>
         .checkbox-container {}
         .checkbox-container label { display: block; }
         .checkbox-container ul {}
         .checkbox-container ul ul { list-style: none;  display: none;  }
         .checkbox-container ul { list-style: none;  display: block; }
         
        .checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"] {}
        
    </style>
<div class="checkbox-container">
        <ul>
            <li class="first">
                <input type="checkbox" name="100" value="100" >100
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="110" value="110" >110</li>    
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="120" value="120" >120
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" name="121" value="121" >121</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" name="122" value="122" >122</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" name="123" value="123" >123
                                <ul>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="1230" value="1230" >1230</li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="1231" value="1231" >1231</li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="1232" value="1231" >1231</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when you uncheck a checkbox? Uncheck its children and/or hide its children but leave parents unchanged?

Comment: here is the example please check :http://jsfiddle.net/manoj2010/6296B/
follow step :
1. checked on 100
2. then checked on 120
3. then checked on 123
4. then un-check 123

you will got the issue automaticly

Comment: @ManojPrajapat Can You Explain What You want to do when uncheck?

Comment: In the else statement, use parent instead of parents, however consider that child checkboxes may still be checked (is this what you want for postback?)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `.parent()` instead of `.parents()`.

Comment: I mistakenly swapped the demo so it showed that yours wasn't working. you got my +1

Answer (score 1):

It should be `parent()` instead of `parents()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".checkbox-container input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $(this).parent("li").children("ul").show(600);
         } else {
             $(this).parent("li").children("ul").hide(600);
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: `.parent()` traverses only single level up the DOM tree. So `.parent("li")` is not valid here.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fK2zc/)

You can just use `.siblings()` - **[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to get the `<ul>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkbox-container input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).siblings("ul").show(600);
            } else {
                $(this).siblings("ul").hide(600);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Other alternative : `.next()`